# Chrome intermittently reject FB SDK due to CSP header

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, content-security-policy

We are using a Content Security Policy on key areas of our website, using the 'nonce' method, whereby a random nonce is added to script tags, with this nonce whitelisted in our CSP policy.

For example:

`"script-src data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-42d55d4787a9898dc31a5a8fe9030ab6' 'strict-dynamic' https:  ;  upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;  report-uri https://xxx.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce;",`

We're then loading in the FB SDK as follows:

`<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js"  nonce='42d55d4787a9898dc31a5a8fe9030ab6'></script>`

This works fine, 99% of the time, but our Report URI stats are showing us random rejections of the above script on Chrome

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://xxx",
        "referrer": "xxx",
        "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
        "original-policy": "script-src data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-[removed]' 'strict-dynamic' https:  ;  upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;  report-uri https://xxx.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce;",
        "blocked-uri": "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js"
    }
}
```

It's always the same issue, with 'script-src-elem' failing (which should fall back to 'script-src' and that has the nonce correctly whitelisted)

I'm confuses as to why this would work most of the time but fail on others. I can refresh the page and occasionally reproduce this, but then refresh again and it goes.

All I can think is that it's either a Chrome bug, or something the FB SDK is doing strangely...?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a Chrome bug which has now been fixed